# get JSON response using AWS presigned url

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I'm able to generate a presigned url like so

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
url = s3.generate_presigned_url( ClientMethod='list_objects', Params={'Bucket':'bucket-name'} )

# now get the listing
import requests
r = requests.get(url)

# r.status_code is 200
# Problem:  r.text output is in XML format
```

When I do a direct call `s3.list_objects(Bucket='bucket-name')` then I get the response in JSON.  There is no option to specify content type when generating the url.  I've tried updating the headers of the request with `accept: application/json`, but that results in a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error from AWS.

Ultimately I will be using the URL client-side with javascript.  This example is just to illustrate the problem.

How do I get the response in JSON when using a presigned URL (preferably using boto)? Seems like it should be possible.

Comment: To prompt an API to return the response as JSON, you typically send `Accept: application/json` -- not `Content-Type:`.  S3, however, does not generate JSON responses.

Comment: Ahh, right, yes I tried setting the `Accept` header as well and it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this, S3 only returns XML. `boto3` has response parsing that converts it into a dictionary for ease of use.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in their documentation stating this.  I tested a call using their REST API and got back XML, even with the `Accept` header set to `application/json` so evidently this is correct.  If you can add a reference to the documentation I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: lps, there is no place in their docs where they explicitly say "we are XML only". However, there is also nowhere they document being able to return JSON. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) is the doc page for the request you're making. Note that all the documented responses are XML and there is no documented mechanism for altering that.